# Connect to FTP server in C#

Tags: c#, ftp

Trying to connect to an FTP server using a port just to see if it work.

If I use port 21 I get an error: 530 Not logged in and if I use port 22 I get an error the server committed a protocol violation.

I made sure my firewall is off, is there anything else to check or my code is wrong?

```
try
{
    FtpWebRequest directoryListRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.fakeURL.com:22/");
    directoryListRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
    directoryListRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

    using (FtpWebResponse directoryListResponse = (FtpWebResponse)directoryListRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader directoryListResponseReader = new StreamReader(directoryListResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string responseString = directoryListResponseReader.ReadToEnd();
            string[] results = responseString.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Port 22 is for SSH. That likely won't work well with FTP

Comment: FTP requires a credential (username password) on some servers.  So port 21 is correct but you need a login.   You can try two thing manually to see what works 1) from cmd.exe >FTP url    The you will be asked for password.  Some server use a default like Anonymous  2) From Browser FTP://URL

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for the suggestion, that help narrow the problem.

Comment: So did you resolve the problem? Or do you still need a help? We you able to login with any FTP client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use Fluent FTP library to upload the file and it made my life way easier.
below an example of the code I used.

```
public static async Task UploadFileAsync() {
    var token = new CancellationToken();
    using (var ftp = new FtpClient("127.0.0.1", "ftptest", "ftptest")) {
        await ftp.ConnectAsync(token);

        // upload a file to an existing FTP directory
        await ftp.UploadFileAsync(@"D:\Github\FluentFTP\README.md", "/public_html/temp/README.md");

        // upload a file and ensure the FTP directory is created on the server
        await ftp.UploadFileAsync(@"D:\Github\FluentFTP\README.md", "/public_html/temp/README.md", FtpRemoteExists.Overwrite, true);

        // upload a file and ensure the FTP directory is created on the server, verify the file after upload
        await ftp.UploadFileAsync(@"D:\Github\FluentFTP\README.md", "/public_html/temp/README.md", FtpRemoteExists.Overwrite, true, FtpVerify.Retry);
    }
}
```